# Full table scan over indexed columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, indexing

I have the following query:

```
select 
    Table1.Id,
    Table1.SomeColumn1,
    Table1.SomeColumn2,
    Table1.SomeColumn3
    Table2.Id,
    Table2.SomeColumn,
from   
    Table1 
inner join 
    Table2 on Table1.Table2_Id = Table2.Id
inner join 
    Table3 on Table3.Id = Table2.Table3_Id
where  
    Table3.Some_Column = 181715
```

- Table1.Table2_Id is indexed (non-clustered)
- Table2.Table3_Id is indexed (non-clustered)
- Table3.Some_Column is indexed (non-clustered)
- All primary keys are indexed (clustered index)

Despite that, the query's performance is terrible.

Query execution plan looks following:
https://snipboard.io/Xd67ru.jpg

As we can see, the database engine is making full table scan over Table1, which is completely unnecessary (as all joins are over indexed columns).

What is wrong? How to improve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just a guess - but what I'd try first would be to make those indexes **covering**, e.g. adding some additional columns as **included** columns to those so that the query can be satisfied from the nonclustered index - instead of having to go back to the base table with an expensive "Key Lookup" to grab more columns.

Try to update your indexes to:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_Table1
ON dbo.Table1(Table2_Id)    --- create index on foreign key column
INCLUDE (SomeColum1, SomeColumn2, SomeColumn3);

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_Table2
ON dbo.Table2(Table3_Id)
INCLUDE (SomeColumn);
```

With these "covering" indexes, the whole query (all the columns you need as results) as present in the leaf level of those indexes - so just by using index lookups, the whole query can be "satisfied". This should avoid expensive key lookups into the base table, and probably will also cause the "full table scan" to go away.

Give it a try!

Comment: Looks like it works.
Can I to this on existing indexes, or should I create another ones?
If I do this on existing indexes, could it impact performance on other selections?

Comment: @JakubSzułakiewicz: there's no point in having two indexes - replace your existing ones (that probably have only the indexed column) with those that also have the "included" columns

Comment: @marc_s - How about starting a code formatting war regarding your edit with the `inner join's`? The original is more readable to me :p